# Floyd's Shortest Path Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I think I'm having some issues here
Here's the matrix I'm given
[image]

I'm supposed to find the costs of paths passing through vertex k = 0,
1, 2, and 3.
For vertex k=0,  have

0, 10, 30, inf

15, 0, inf, inf

inf, 5, 0, 2

30, 40, 33, 0

Is that correct? Is anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the intermediate result for `k=1` would be as follows.

```
000 010 003 inf
015 000 018 inf
inf 005 000 002
030 004 033 000
```

For intutitive understanding, the entry with indices `i` and `j` would be the shortest path from `i` to `j` where intermediate noted from the set `{1}` are permitted, i.e. the better path from either going from `i` to `j` or the path `i-0-j`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to interpret your (intermediate?) result. The first line reads:

```
0, 10, 30, inf
```

Which means that there's a path from vertex 0 to 0 with 0 cost, trivially, a path from vertex 0 to 1 with minimum cost 10, and a path from vertex 0 to 2 with minimum cost 30. This cannot be, as there is an even cheaper path from vertex 0 to 2, with cost 3, given by the initial cost matrix. Therefore your implementation has a bug. If you could share it, we might also be able to point it out.

PS. Even if it were an intermediate result, costs in the matrix will never increase by Floyd-Warshall, only decrease. (Ex: prove it)